# validating textboxes using jquery

Tags: jquery, validation

Using jQuery, I need to validate my form `onsubmit()` and if the two text boxes both have a non-null value, display an error below them.

HTML:

```
<input id="actual" type="text" value="#" />
<input id="real" type="text" value="#" />
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
```

jQuery:

```
$("[value='Submit']").click(function(event) {
    if (($("#actual").val() != null) && ($("#real").val() != null)) {
        // What do I do here?
    }
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by throw error? Do you want to use catch or just want to alert user for an error?

Comment: This question is written no better than your first version.  Possible duplicate of [validating textboxes on submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547552/validating-textboxes-on-submit)

Answer (score 0):

First: Your if syntax is completely wrong. Second point is, your checking the value of the same element twice.

What do you mean by throw an error? Actually throw an exception? You do this like this:

```
if($("#first_textbox").val() != null && $("#second_textbox").val() != null) {
    throw new Error("Both textboxes are empty.")
}
```

Or do you want to wrap a error styled class around the textbox?

```
if($("#first_textbox").val() != null) {
    $("#first_textbox").addClass('error');
}

if($("#second_textbox").val() != null) {
    $("#second_textbox").addClass('error');
}
```

Of course you have to declare a CSS class that adds an error like style. You could create a style like this:

```
.error {
    border-color: #8B1A1A;
}
```

Also please do not add click handlers on a selector, that matches the value part of an input button.

Instead of `$("[value='Submit']")` use `$('input[type="submit"]')`

**Updated**

Comment: what do I need to specify in that error class, how to do it? I am new to CSS